# Firebase hosting deploy - Cannot read property 'deploys' of undefined

Tags: firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

I'm trying to deploy an angular app to Firebase. Firebase is setup to host multiple sites.

In Firebase, the project name is 'myapp-staging-84e3e'.
There are two sites setup in Firebase which are 'myapp-admin-staging' and 'myapp-staging-84e3e'. I'm trying to deploy this app to 'myapp-admin-staging'.

When I try to run `firebase deploy --only hosting:admin` I get the following error in `firebase-debug.log`;

```
[debug] [2020-08-24T15:19:23.581Z] TypeError: Cannot read property 'deploys' of undefined
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/index.js:84:36
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:5)
[error] 
[error] Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
```

I must have something setup incorrectly but I can't determine what it is. My `.firebaserc` file looks like this;

```
    {
  "targets": {
    "myapp-staging-84e3e": {
      "hosting": {
        "admin": [
          "myapp-admin-staging"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "projects": {
    "default": "myapp-staging-84e3e"
  }
}
```

Then the `firebase.json` file looks like this;

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist/MyApp-Admin",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add  `"target": "admin"` to your `firebase.json` so that it looks like this:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "target": "admin", //added
    "public": "dist/MyApp-Admin",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```